# How do I group by a key that could be nil and get a dictionary with a non-optional key type?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
enum UKCountry : String {
    case england, scotland, wales, northernIreland

    init?(placeName: String) {
        // magic happens here
    }
}

struct LocalPopulation {
    let place: String
    let population: Int
}
```

The `init(placeName:)` takes an arbitrary string and figures out where it is. For example `init(placeName: "London")` gives `.england`. How it does this is not important.

I also have a `[LocalPopulation]` I want to process. Specifically, I want to get a `[UKCountry: [LocalPopulation]]`. I could do this:

```
let populations: [LocalPopulation] = [...]
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: populations, by: { UKCountry(placeName: $0.place)! })
```

But not all places in the `populations` is a place in the UK, so `UKCountry.init` would return `nil`, and it would crash. Note that I do not want any place that is not in the UK in the result. I could `filter` it before hand:

```
let populations: [LocalPopulation] = [...]
let filteredPopulations = populations.filter { UKCountry(placeName: $0.place) != nil }
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: populations, by: { UKCountry(placeName: $0.place)! })
```

But that means running `UKCountry.init` twice. Depending on how it is implemented, this could be costly. The other way I thought of is:

```
let populations: [LocalPopulation] = [...]
var dict = Dictionary(grouping: populations, by: { UKCountry(placeName: $0.place) })
dict[nil] = nil
let result = dict as! [UKCountry: [LocalPopulation]]
```

But that's a bit too "procedural"... What's more annoying is, in all the above attempts, I have used `!`. I know sometimes `!` is unavoidable, but I'd like to avoid it whenever I can.

How can I do this Swiftily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, allow dictionaries to easily be created from grouped key-value pairs:

```
public extension Dictionary {
  /// Group key-value pairs by their keys.
  ///
  /// - Parameter pairs: Either `Swift.KeyValuePairs<Key, Self.Value.Element>`
  ///   or a `Sequence` with the same element type as that.
  /// - Returns: `[ KeyValuePairs.Key: [KeyValuePairs.Value] ]`
  init<Value, KeyValuePairs: Sequence>(grouping pairs: KeyValuePairs)
  where
    KeyValuePairs.Element == (key: Key, value: Value),
    Self.Value == [Value]
  {
    self =
      Dictionary<Key, [KeyValuePairs.Element]>(grouping: pairs, by: \.key)
      .mapValues { $0.map(\.value) }
  }

  /// Group key-value pairs by their keys.
  ///
  /// - Parameter pairs: Like `Swift.KeyValuePairs<Key, Self.Value.Element>`,
  ///   but with unlabeled elements.
  /// - Returns: `[ KeyValuePairs.Key: [KeyValuePairs.Value] ]`
  init<Value, KeyValuePairs: Sequence>(grouping pairs: KeyValuePairs)
  where
    KeyValuePairs.Element == (Key, Value),
    Self.Value == [Value]
  {
    self.init( grouping: pairs.map { (key: $0, value: $1) } )
  }
}
```

Then, create a key-value sequence that's like `KeyValuePairs<Key, Value.Element>`, where `Key` and `Value` belong to your desired `[ UKCountry: [LocalPopulation] ]` type – but you don't need to bother with labeled elements.

```swift
Dictionary(
  grouping: populations.compactMap { population in
    UKCountry(placeName: population.place).map { ($0, population) }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `reduce` to transform your `[LocalPopulation]` into a `[UKCountry:[LocalPopulation]]` by also filtering out all elements which aren't in the UK.

```
let dict = populations.reduce(into: [UKCountry:[LocalPopulation]](), { currentResult, population in
    if let ukCountry = UKCountry(placeName: population.place) {
        currentResult[ukCountry, default: []].append(population)
    }
})
```